# Swift - Strange text rendering at runtime

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am working on an iOS app right now. I usually use the Interface Builder and recently it has been producing an issue. When the storyboard is seen in Xcode the labels on everything look fine, but some UI elements don't render properly at runtime. This has also happened for some of the images in this project. The only font used is the system font.

I have tried readjusting the font and using attributed text, but this hasn't worked for the specific label shown. Just to mention, this app is a shared project through Git so it may be an issue with it pulling incorrectly or something, but that seems odd for it to affect the text after it has been changed and adjusted.

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqUhe.jpg)

The results should be crystal clear text on iOS, but it results in "fuzzy" text you would expect if you were running the Windows XP on a 480p screen. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: See if the view's layer has shouldRasterize set to true and set it to false if so.
yourLabel.layer.shouldRasterize = false

Comment: So I tried that out, and it didn't seem to change anything. Unfortunately the text is the same. I will keep that as false in case it messes with anything in the future.

Comment: Does it help if you don't set the text directly on the UILabel, but rather as attributedText?

Comment: So the image I posted was actually directly from the app. The text was pulled from CloudKit and was put into the UILabel.

Comment: Yes, but I assume it is set as yourLabel.text = "String"? Can you set it with yourLabel.attributedText = yourAttributedString and see if that works?

Comment: Sure. I’ll hit up my friend who’s been working on the project with me since he’s working on it right now.

Comment: It seems, that my friend who was working on it had another shouldRasterize statement that I didn’t see. Sorry for wasting your time and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the layer of a superview of the `UILabel` in the provided image is set to pre-render. This is good for performance reasons but may not always look as good, as is seen here.

If you're setting a custom layer on a superview of the `UILabel`, try setting the layer's `shouldRasterize` to `false`.

Ex: `exampleLayer.shouldRasterize = false`